# What do the special characters in an ffmpeg file output format mean?

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to process some videos with ffmpeg, and I found an example command that does almost everything I need it to:

```
ffmpeg -i example.avi -vf fps=1/30 example_%03d.jpg
```

I've figured out what all of this command does, but I've been unable to figure out the meaning of `%03d` in the output file format. **What does `%03d` mean in a ffmpeg file output format mean? What other special sequences are allowed in an ffmpeg output?**

Comment: formatting chars, look up C's `printf()` function... `%03d` is a (d)ecimal (aka integer), `3` digits long, padded with `0` to the left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html):

> The syntax foo-%03d.jpeg specifies to use a decimal number composed of three digits padded with zeroes to express the sequence number. It is the same syntax supported by the C printf function, but only formats accepting a normal integer are suitable.

So the resulting file names are `example_001.jpg`, `example_002.jpg`, … , `example_123.jpg`.

See also [the *"image sequence"* entry in the *FFMPEG An Intermediate Guide*](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence) for details and examples.