# why doesn't ffmpeg name files with sequence after using strftime?

Tags: ffmpeg, output, filenames, strftime

I would like to know why ffmpeg stops naming my files with a sequence number (%03d) when using -strftime 1?

for example: `filename_%Y-%m-%d_%03d.ts`

I need to get filename_YEAR_MONTH_DAY_SEQUENCE#.ts

references:
[What do the special characters in an ffmpeg file output format mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186410/what-do-the-special-characters-in-an-ffmpeg-file-output-format-mean)
[ffmpeg filename output format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544816/ffmpeg-filename-output-format/23006062#23006062)
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence

Comment: Because the pattern is being passed to `strftime()` for expansion, in which %d is reserved for date.